# Creating and filling an array of objects with two parameters

Tags: java

I am making baby steps into working with objects and arrays of objects, came into the following problem and I can't figure out what's causing it. For some context, the app I am making is sort of a calculator.

To sum it up, I have two arrays who have already been filled. The first array contains the indexes of where the numeric elements begin. The second array contains the elements themselves. I want to create an array of objects(with two attributes, the attributes being: the indexes and the elements.

`int numericElementCounter;`
// The variable numericElementCounter's value is known at this point and it is used to determine the length of the arrays.
`int[] IndexBeginning = new int[numericElementCounter];` //Contains the starting indexes of each Numeric element.
`double[] NumericElementsDouble = new double[numericElementCounter];` //Contains the elements themselves.

//There is 'for' loop here, which fills the arrays initialized above, but I doubt that's part of the problem, will add it upon request.

`NumericElements[] NumericElementsObjects = new NumericElements[numericElementCounter];` //This is the attempt to initialize the array of objects.

```
public class NumericElements {

    int IndexStart;
    double NumericElement;

    public NumericElements(int x, double y) {
    int IndexStart = x;
    double NumericElement = y;
    }

}

//This is the 'for' loop that attempts to fill the array of objects.
for(int n=0;n<numericElementCounter;n++){
            System.out.println("The element starts at: " + IndexBeginning[n]);
            System.out.println("The element itself is: " + NumericElementsDouble[n]);
            NumericElementsObjects[n] = new NumericElements(IndexBeginning[n], NumericElementsDouble[n]);
            System.out.println("The object's IndexStart attribute: " + NumericElementsObjects[n].IndexStart + " The object's numericElement attribute: " + NumericElementsObjects[n].NumericElement);
        }
```

**For example**, 
**Input is:**
`String UserInput = "  234 + 256 + 278  ";`

**Actual Output:**

```
The element starts at 2
The element itself is: 234.0
The object's IndexStart attribute: 0 The object's numericElement attribute: 0.0
The element starts at 8
The element itself is: 256.0
The object's IndexStart attribute: 0 The object's numericElement attribute: 0.0
The element starts at 14
The element itself is: 278.0
The object's IndexStart attribute: 0 The object's numericElement attribute: 0.0
```

**I've tried** to minimize the code in a way that I provide only what is needed if you guys feel like something is missing I will post the entire code.
The expectations are for the attributes of the objects, part of the array of objects to be filled. But they remain at value `0/0.0`

Comment: In your `NumericElements` constructor, you are not assigning to the fields.Try `IndexStart = x; NumericElement = y;`

Comment: But you should definitely follow the Java Naming Conventions. Variable names and method names are written in camelCase, that means they start with lowercase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constructor is incorrect, you have to set the value of the attributes using `this`

Here's the correct constructor:

```
public NumericElements(int x, double y) {
    this.IndexStart = x;
    this.NumericElement = y;
    }
```

Comment: And I suggest you to not use capitalized words for attributes names. It's a good Java standard

Answer (score 0):

You are doing well. There is only a minor issue here in your constructor.

```
//here you shouldn't create a new variable, instead you should assign them to the variable inside your classs
public NumericElements(int x, double y) {
   this.IndexStart = x;
   this.NumericElement = y;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your NumericElements contructor you are not assigning values to the fields IndexStart and NumericElement. You are creating new local variables which are limited in scope to the contstructor. You can just modify the constructor like below and you should have what you are looking for:

```
public NumericElements(int x, double y) {
    this.IndexStart = x;
    this.NumericElement = y;
}
```

or you could also do:

```
public NumericElements(int x, double y) {
    IndexStart = x;
    NumericElement = y;
}
```

In both the cases, you will get the same result. this is generally used to refer to the fields and methods of the object of the same class. It is a reference to the same object for which you are trying to access fields or methods. The code will work perfectly fine even without this since Java does it for you.